# How can I sort X-Axis and Legend Entries?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a dashboard where I am measuring a metric value for different items during the day and then displaying it on Google Data Studio.

On the X-axis, I am displaying time of day in hhmm format (internally this is a number) and on the Y-axis I have the metric value with different lines for different items.

I want to display X-Axis in chronological order and the legend entries for different items in descending order of cumulative metric value. This should be more clear from the image here:

[image: 1]

There is a sort option available in Google Data Studio but its not very clear on demarcation between X-Axis and the legend.

- [Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZnF1OlQ6r0AzW1UB_hHs9davaC6HcpU5VuyDEi2xc2Q/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/f54a7ba8-6e94-43c1-ab59-13da322dbee6)

Answer (score 2):

Display the time is chronological order by setting the X-axis **Sort** in the [line chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7398001) to:

- ***Field***: `TIME`
- ***Order***: `Ascending`

To sort the `ITEM` values in legend by cumulative `METRIC`, change the **Secondary Sort** to:

- ***Field***: `Metric`
- ***Aggregation***: [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212)
- ***Order***: `Descending`

Additionally, to ensure that all 11 items are displayed change the `Number of Series` (in the **Style Tab**) from the default, 10, to the required number, with 20, currently being the maximum number of unique series (lines) that can be displayed simultaneously.

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f74838f2-5f02-4164-a022-4c6f2d24c3b7) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VURndYtLhKqt3IJV7Wdgz6O07m6l095EGy7oOG58D4/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]